# How to navigate to nested router via code

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How can I create this link via code:
*'foo' being the name of the router-outlet, and 'bar' the name of the component.*
http://localhost:8000/Home/(foo:bar)

I used to do it in HTML like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {foo: ['Bar']}}]">Bar</a>
```

But I'm unable to navigate to the same URL via code:

```
this._router.navigate([{ outlets: { foo: bar} }], { relativeTo: this._route });
```

In the console I get this:

> NavigationError(id: 3, url: '/Home(foo:bar)', error: Error:
>   Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'bar')

This **/** between 'Home' and '(foo:bar)' is missing: /Home/(foo:bar)'

**Update based on comment:**
I have a page 'Home' that contains my navigation bar.
Under that navigation bar I have a 'named router-outlet' that displays the pages that users browse to.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Can you create a plunker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the prefix myself:

```
this._router.navigate(['Home', { outlets: { foo: bar} }]);
```